# How to calculate how many trials I need to guess the plain text if a simple P-Box is used to make the cipher text

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, transposition-cipher

If I have 64 bit as input for a straight box that use a transposition process to encipher the plain text and the given 64 bits contains 60 bits as (1s), then how many trial I should do?

Comment: If the entire scheme consists of a single permutation step, then it is not encryption at all. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: how many trial I should do to guess the plain text ?

Comment: I just said that your question doesn't make any sense. Try adding more clarification. Also, there's no such thing as a straight box. You might be thinking of an s-box, which wouldn't work on 64 bits at once. Add more context. Tell me what you are trying to accomplish (don't just say guess the plaintext, I can read. Your question is incomprehensible right now. I have no idea what you are asking.) Don't just restate your poorly phrased question.